# 3 Player Hand and Foot Canasta

Tags: canasta

I was taught to play Hand and Foot Canasta while I was in Rehab at a nursing home by these older women. I have not been able to find a game where this "version" is played anymore. (in fact, those women have adopted a new way now since I left!) I have tried to find people interested in playing but usually only wind up with one, maybe two people! (I'm just not charismatic enough, I guess) Is it possible to play H&F with THREE PEOPLE? Would that work? I guess we would have to have a rule where the partner would not be able to pick up the discard pile if their partner throws something down they could use. But are there any other problems?

Comment: Are you asking if you can play with 3 people? If that is the case you should make your title more clear.

Comment: lol, I thought by saying "3 player" that was pretty clear. I forgot to add an "s".   3 people playing the game. Yes, three people. Thanks for making me clear it up.

Comment: It's not the lack of the any s, there shouldn't even be another s there as written (though player is better than saying handed) the question title should tell people what your question is asking, something like "Can you play Hand and Foot Canasta with 3 Players?" would be best.

Comment: Oh, I see. It was my mistake. I saw "Title" and figured they only meant for me to put a subject matter in that box. Not the actual question. And then below I thought I was supposed to ask the question. First time here, I didn't know.

Comment: Not a problem, your title is all people see on the home view, and people are more likely to go into a question when they believe they can answer what you're asking from that.

Answer (score 2):

In 3 player Canasta, Hand and Foot or any other variant, there wouldn't be any "partners", so there is no rule issue discarding something your partner could use.

There is no 1 official ruleset for Hand and Foot Canasta, but there are sources that say that the player count does not have to be 4:

https://www.pagat.com/rummy/handfoot.html

> Any number of people from two to six can play, using one more deck of cards than the number of players. Four or six can play as partners; with two three or five, everyone must play for themselves.

https://playingcarddecks.com/blogs/how-to-play/hand-and-foot-game-rules

> Hand and Foot uses about 5 or 6 decks of standard playing cards and is played with 2-6 players.

Comment: Yes, I know if there are only 3 people playing H & F Canasta, that normally they would play individually. What I am asking is, if we three people played as one team against one person, what kind of problems might there be? I have only been playing the game for about 5 years. I've never done that before (two against one) but I just wanted to find out if anyone has ever done it. Thanks

Comment: I also did that very thing today, it was okay. We just had to stipulate that the partner was not allowed to pick up the discard pile once their partner discarded. We played two games and both times the single person got clobbered. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Your question was not clear on that point at all. Hand and Foot already works normally as a 3-player game without any partnerships, so I'm not sure why would try to play a variant where you use uneven teams. Some games are designed around that concept; but they require all sorts of rules to deal with the fact that the game is 2 vs 1 while still being fair. You can't just take a game designed around equal teams and expect it to be fair when teams are not equal.